# Как дебажить segfault на ideone?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, ideone

http://ideone.com/f0239W

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[256];
    int i;

    while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
    {
        printf("Going to assign #%d\n", i);
        s[i] = 'Q';
    }

    printf("%d", strlen(s)); // Use s to eliminate optimizer

    return 0;
}
```

```
17
19
348
-3007
478999879
```

Выводится

> Ошибка выполнения time: 0 memory: 2172 signal:11

> stdout
>   Standard output is empty

Но очевидно, что ошибка не могла произойти на записи по индексам 17 и 19, т. е. должны быть выведены как минимум две строки. Почему их нет и какие ещё способы отладки segfault'ов на ideone существуют?

Comment: это саммоответ?

Comment: @pavel, уже да. Я ступил когда не получилось...

Comment: а так флашить вывод помогло бы думаю)

Comment: @pavel, да, именно оно. Но меня сначала угораздило вместо `fflush(stdout)` написать `fflush(stdin)`, что не прокатило. Поэтому я задал этот вопрос, а уже потом дошло, что накосячил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy вызвано опечаткой и больше не воспроизводится? :)

Comment: @alexolut, ну в вопросе же не сказано, что fflush не работает, так что не опечаткой :)

Comment: Причина появления вопроса вызвана опечаткой, а ответ на него - нет :)

Comment: @alexolut, ну это да))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо после вывода добавить `fflush(stdout)`:

http://ideone.com/PgNBUA

```
printf("Going to assign #%d\n", i);
fflush(stdout);
```

> ```
> Going to assign #17
> Going to assign #19
> Going to assign #348
> Going to assign #-3007
> Going to assign #478999879
> ```